# HTTP Status 404 - Invalid path was requested

Tags: java, struts

I am developing an application using struts1.2.9 and the following is my folder structure.
[image]

Once I login to the system it is fine and I get no issue, following is the home page.
[image]

and when I click on the menu which is there at the left side than I get the following exception and the page looks like this

```
HTTP Status 404 - Invalid path was requested
```

[image]

my menu link is like this : `<a href=\"#\" target=\"workFrame\" onclick=\"getMenuRequest('DepartmentAction','goToHome')\">"Department"</a>`

and this is the javascript:

```
function getMenuRequest(actionName,methodName){
                       document.forms[0].action=actionName+".htm";
                       document.forms[0].method.value=methodName;
                       document.forms[0].submit();
                   }
```

the following is my action class method:

```
public ActionForward goToHome(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        //call method to verify Pagetoken
        forwardRequestTo = "departmentHome";
        return mapping.findForward(forwardRequestTo);
    }
```

and the following is the struts-config.xml

```
<action path="/DepartmentAction" name="SecurEyesForm" type="com.secureyes.eswastha.struts.action.DepartmentAction" scope="request" parameter="method" validate="false">
            <forward name="departmentHome" path="/WEB-INF/Masters/DepartmentMaster.jsp"></forward>            
        </action>
```

I am using framsets.

Now when I click on the menu name it is giving the above exception.

Please help.

Regards

Comment: thanks for the guy who down voted,but should have commented why?

Comment: There is no meaning in down voting unless you give comment for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 document.forms[0].action=actionName+".htm";
```

should be changed to

```
 document.forms[0].action=actionName+".do";
```

i am assuming *.do to be the url mapping for ActionServlet in web.xml
replace *.do with your extension (check your web.xml)

Comment: Thanks for the info but it did not help as this will not be an issue

Comment: @JavaQuestions: Considering above comment, may I ask why you accepted the answer?

Comment: Downvoting this as it seems to only help a completely unrelated issue.